# pre populate form data on page re load from the session storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML from to capture string data. I am saving those when I hit the save button via ajax. But the scope also includes saving the data on a sessionstorage once I focus out of the form field with the orange save button after it checks the value is not empty. The idea is to pre populate each form field with values stored in the session storage. Everything works fine but I just cant figure out the session storage part. The hard part is how to assign a unique key for each form field, and use that key to find and preload values in the field.

Here is my JS

```
$('.wrapper').remove()

function renderInput() {
    var inputField = '<div class="wrapper"><input class="zoom-text-field" type="text" value=""/><span class="close">save</span></div>';
    return inputField;
}

function hideZoomFiled(e, textData) {
    $(e).parent().parent().children('.students-name-collection').val(textData);
    console.log(textData)
    $(e).parent().hide();
    $('.students-name-collection').attr('disabled', false);
    $(e).prop('disabled', false);
}

function disableInputField(obj) {
    $('.students-name-collection').attr('disabled', false);
    $(obj).attr('disabled', true);
}

$('.students-name-collection').on('focus', function () {
    disableInputField(this);
    $(this).next('.wrapper').focus();
    $('.wrapper').remove();
    $(this).parent().append(renderInput());

    var textData = '';
    $('.close').on('click', function () {
        textData = $(this).parent().children().val();
        hideZoomFiled(this, textData);
    });

    $('.zoom-text-field').on('blur', function(){
        if($(this).val() !== ''){
            //save the value in the sessionstorage
//This is where I am getting lost

        }
    });
});

$('#submitForm').on('click', function(){
    sessionStorage.clear();
})

// on page load read the session storage and pre fill the form fields
```

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/ykshgrxg/5/

Comment: Have you looked up [how to use SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), and have tried to implement it?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek -- yes
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/ykshgrxg/6/

I am getting null.

Comment: That example is saving that data to the session storage. [I've added a `console.log()` to show that](http://jsfiddle.net/ykshgrxg/7/). Enter a value and click "save", then click "run", and you will notice the data is there.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek -- can you share the link where you did that?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek -- my question is really not how to save the data on a session storage really. I am sure that is probably the least complicated task. My question is around how to update the storage data if  same form field is updated etc. Maybe I should have been little bit more clear about the question

Comment: Yes, the hard part here is how to assign a unique key for each form field, and use that key to find and preload values in the field. In the question it seems as if you simply do not know how to use sessionStorage. I understand the problem.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek -- yep..that is exactly where I am getting lost. I just updated the question with your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can handle this, as you pointed out the main problem here is how to figure out how to save each input item, and how to place it back when the page loads. What you can do is give each item an `index`, from `0` to `4`.

To get the index of the element you are on, you can add an `selected` class to it, then use that class in order to find the elements position by using `.index($('.selected'))`, of course we can remove that class when we are done with it. This can be used as the `key` for the sessionStorage, then the `textData` is the value:

```
// Get the index of the input item we are on
$(this).addClass("selected");
var key = $(".students-name-collection").index($('.selected'));
$(this).removeClass("selected");

$('.close').on('click', function () {
    var textData = $(this).parent().children().val();
    hideZoomFiled(this, textData);
    if(!!textData){
        //save the value in the sessionstorage
       sessionStorage.setItem(key, textData);
    }
});
```

Then for loading them in you can use jQuerys `.each` and have that on the class `.students-name-collection` using an index of `sessionStorage` to give each input the correct value:

```
// on page load read the session storage and pre fill the form fields 
$('.students-name-collection').each(function(index) {
    if(sessionStorage[index])
        $(this).val(sessionStorage[index]) 
});
```

[**Here is a Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ykshgrxg/9/)